# How to create TensorFlow checkpoint without a session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I want to speed up a tool for averaging a number of TensorFlow checkpoints, but for simplicity let's say I need just to load one checkpoint, possibly modify some variables and save it to back to disk.

The [current implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/utils/avg_checkpoints.py) loads all variables to numpy arrays (3 seconds), prepares tf variables (`tf.get_variable()`), placeholders and assign_ops for each variable (20s), executes a session where it initializes all variables (16s), runs all assignments (81s) and finally it stores the checkpoint to disk (24s). The total time is **144 seconds**.

My alternative implementation uses `tf.get_variable(name, shape=numpy_array.shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(numpy_array))` and no placeholders nor assign_ops, so it cuts down the total time to **57 seconds**. However, the `*.meta` file stores also all the constant initializers (so it is as big as the main checkpoint data file, which is not what I want) and when I apply this on bigger checkpoints, it fails because of the [2GB tf limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388563/tensorflow-graphdef-cannot-be-larger-than-2gb-error-when-saving-model-after).

If loading all variables takes 3 seconds, I believe storing them should take much less than 141 seconds and even **less than 54 seconds**. Is there a way to write a dict `{var_name1: numpy_array1,...}` into tf checkpoint files (reusing the metagraph from another checkpoint) without a need to run a tf session? I tried to follow the links in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325245/edit-a-tensorflow-checkpoint) with no success.